# NSDictionary to JSON file

Tags: json, database, editor, nsdictionary

I have a plist file that i want to store in my database as a JSON string compiled from an NSDictionary.
i've been searching for hours on the web to find tools that do this but i can't find any.
I'm also not in the mood to start writing it myself.

So if you guys know any tools that do this, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OS X, have a look at plutil. This will convert a plist file into a JSON string and write it to stdout:

```
plutil -convert json -o - myFile.plist
```